How to read MapContext from jobClient (or another API)?
I'm submitting a job in a hadoop cluster.
This job has a file and is using InputFormatClass = NLineInputFormat.
After the job starts, it will create several map tasks, each one with a line of the input file.
How to get that information after job submit and all tasks running?
I'm trying to get MapContext from jobClient to get map task information.
